# How to disable tableView scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift

When I add a tableView in a viewController by default the tableView scrolls, but I want it static. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return names.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.username.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 50.0
}
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by the row moves ?

Comment: do you want to disable scrolling of tableView ?

Comment: You want to keep certain rows of the tableview fixed and the rest let it move

Comment: yaaa @ supratik majumdar

Comment: I don't understand. On the above comment you said that you want to disable the scrolling. Now you say that you want the same only for some cells

Comment: yaa i want to disable only scrolling in table view

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3, 4 and 5:**

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 6):

Disable Scrolling in Interface Builder.
Select the table view and the Attributes Inspector <kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd>

Then uncheck *Scrolling Enabled*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1**

Try using only this line of code in the **viewDidLoad()**:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.height;
```

This is the abreviated way of:

```
if tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.height {
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true;
}
else {
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false;
}
```

**Explanation:** If there are too many rows and fill more space than the tableview has it will be scrollable. Otherwise it won't. That's why in the code you compare the content size with the window size.

**OPTION 2:**

If you want to disable the scrolling in all cases just this in the **viewDidLoad()** too instead:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false;
```

**NOTE**: If you gave an special name to the tableView replace it with your tableView name in the code I shared you.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll for the **`UITableView`** will be disabled when content size fits on the size of the table view

```
 if (tableView.contentSize.height < tableView.frame.size.height) {

   tableView.scrollEnabled = false
 }
else {

   tableView.scrollEnabled = true
 }
```

If you want to disable scrolling regardless of contentSize:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Change colour of separator lines of **UITableView** (As requested in comments):

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.17, blue:0.20, alpha:1.00)
```

Comment: This code is giving error can you explain little bit more

Comment: There was a mistake with the naming, tableView, Edit made

Comment: This code does not effect on UI of tableview.it cannot disable the scrolling

Comment: One thing more I want to ask can we change the Color of lines of tableview coming default in swift.